# How to Disable Browser Reader view for WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, browser, reader, firefox-reader-view

I want to disable browser reader view in my wordpress website for all users. how can I do this.
/OR/
If user clicks on browser Reader View, then how to redirect to a specific page?

Comment: Browser Reader is for accessibility : it is for people with disabilities...

Comment: But how to stop  copying content from reader view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what user plugins has in chrome.
I think you can not disable that.
Or if user click to some link like "Reader view" than use some a href for that.

> Sorry maybe I am not right, just my IMHO

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.